# XML Error when I run the xml

Tags: xml

Can someone give me an idea what I am doing wrong

```
 The XML page cannot be displayed 
 Cannot view XML input using style sheet. 
 Please correct the error and then click the efresh       
 Button, or try again later. 


A name contained an invalid character. 
Error processing resource 
'file:///C:/Users/Randy/Desktop/faq.xml'. Line 1, Positio...

<?xmlversion"1.0"?encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
------------^
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
"ScanMaster and DigiCam FAQ"
"Randy White 6/11/2011"
<FAQ>
/*
 New Perspectives on XML
 Tutorial 1
 Case Problem 1
 Filename: faq.css

This file contains styles used in the faq.xml file.

 */
 </FAQ>
 FAQ      {margin-top: 10px}
 title    {display: block; width: 500px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
      font-size: 18pt;
      margin-left: 20px}

 subtitle {display: block; width: 500px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serf; 
      font-size:14pt; font-style:italic;
      margin-left: 20px}

 product  {display: block; width: 500px; background-color: ivory;
      border: solid 2px black; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px}

 model    {display: block; width: 500px; font-family: Arial, Helvertica, Sans-serif; 
      font-size: 14pt; color:blue;
      margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px}

 question {display: list-item; list-style-type: disc; width: 500px;
      margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px}

 answer   {display:block; width: 450px; font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif;
      color: green;
      margin-left: 35px}
```

Comment: It would help if you would tell what program is displaying the error message, "The XML page cannot be displayed ..." E.g. Internet Explorer? "Running an XML document" is pretty well meaningless without further explanation.

Comment: IE8 is the web browser I am running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first line with this one. You will see the difference. A space and = is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Comment: The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/Randy/Documents/School/XML/Week1/Case...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

This is the I get now

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a question mark before `encoding`.

It could also be that one of the spaces in the line is actually a non-breaking space, character code `&#xA0;`, instead of a regular space, `&#x20;`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you are getting now...
Your document is not well-formed XML, in that there should be no text content outside the top-level element (`<FAQ>`). You have text content such as

```
"ScanMaster and DigiCam FAQ"
```

before the top-level element, and text content like

```
FAQ      {margin-top: 10px}
```

after it.

In an XML document, the only kinds of nodes allowed outside of the top-level element are comments and processing-instructions. (And of course the prologue, but that's not a node.)

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your original **XML** in word and then copy and save it in word.Use Unicode Text document option for saving the text Document and not other options like rich text format.Using Unicode text document option removes all the formatting that we have done in word.